# Extension methods in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I was searching for an implementation of extension methods in c++ and came upon [this comp.std.c++ discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.std.c++/browse_thread/thread/c8b7234e249bc107) which mentions that `polymorphic_map` can be used to associated methods with a class, but, the provided link seems to be dead.  Does anyone know what that answer was referring to, or if there is another way to extend classes in a similar manner to extension methods (perhaps through some usage of mixins?).

I know the canonical C++ solution is to use free functions; this is more out of curiosity than anything else.

Comment: What do you mean by "extension method"?

Comment: Are you asking about `friend` methods?

Comment: Sorry about that.  I meant `extension methods` in the C# sense.  They allow the programmer to extend a class with extra methods.  ie. in c++ I might want to extend std::string to have a trim member function which could be called like this: `std::string s("  test123"); s.trim(); //s is now equal to "test123"`.  That particular example is very inspiring, compared to a free function, but there are sometimes I would find a chain of method calls must easier to parse and understand then nested free functions.

Comment: My last comment should say "isn't very inspiring".  Is there some way to edit comments;  I can't seem to find one?

Comment: @Bob: You cannot edit a comment that is more than 5 minutes old.

Comment: @Bob: Rather simple: `void trim( std::string& s )`, and then use: `std::string s( " test " ); trim( s );`. Not everything is an object and not every operation has to be a member.

Comment: The Sourceforge project http://p-stade.sourceforge.net/oven/doc/html/index.html works perfectly well.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas try and tell that to C#/Java programmers

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Different languages approach development in different ways. In particular C# and Java have a strong point of view with respect to OO that leads to *everything is an object* mindset (C# is a little more lax here). In that approach, extension methods provide a simple way of extending an existing object or interface to add new features.

There are no extension methods in C++, nor are they needed. When developing C++, forget the everything is an object paradigm --which, by the way, is false even in Java/C# <sup>[*]</sup>. A different mindset is taken in C++, there are objects, and the objects have operations that are inherently part of the object, but there are also other operations that form part of the interface and need not be part of the class. A must read by Herb Sutter is [What's In a Class?](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill02.htm), where the author defends (and I agree) that you can easily extend any given class with simple free functions.

As a particular simple example, the standard templated class `basic_ostream` has a few member methods to dump the contents of some primitive types, and then it is enhanced with (also templated) free functions that extend that functionality to other types by using the existing public interface. For example, `std::cout << 1;` is implemented as a member function, while `std::cout << "Hi";` is a free function implemented in terms of other more basic members.

Extensibility in C++ is achieved by means of free functions, not by ways of adding new methods to existing objects.

[*] Everything is **not** an object.

In a given domain will contain a set of actual objects that can be modeled and operations that can be applied to them, in some cases those operations will be part of the object, but in some other cases they will not. In particular you will find *utility classes* in the languages that claim that everything is an object and those *utility classes* are nothing but a layer trying to hide the fact that those methods don't belong to any particular object.

Even some operations that are implemented as member functions are not really operations on the object. Consider addition for a `Complex` number class, how is `sum` (or `+`) more of an operation on the first argument than the second? Why `a.sum(b);` or `b.sum(a)`, should it not be `sum( a, b )`?

Forcing the operations to be member methods actually produces weird effects --but we are just used to them: `a.equals(b);` and `b.equals(a);` might have completely different results even if the implementation of `equals` is fully symmetric. (Consider what happens when either `a` or `b` is a null pointer)

Comment: I really like the example with the sum.

Comment: This was a really nice writeup.

Comment: @Space_COwbOy: The sum (`operator+`) is a great example in C++, more than I wanted to rant about in the answer itself. Operations that are bound to an object by being *members* of the class cannot be fully symmetric in languages that allow implicit conversions. Consider that the `Complex` class had an implicit conversion from `double` (is a `double` not a `Complex` with no imaginary part?), now implementing `operator+` as a member of the class means that it will be applied to an object of that type that sits in the left hand side of an expression like `a + b`. (cont...)

Comment: (cont'd) Because of the implicit conversion from `double` that means that given objects `d1` and `d2` of type `Complex`, `d1+d2` and `d1+1.5` are valid operations that will be matched to that operator. On the other hand, `1.5+d1` will not. The reason is that the member is applied to the left hand side, and in this particular case that is a `double`, that does not implement that operation. By keeping `operator+` as a free function instead, the compiler will as gladly convert the rhs as the lhs from `double` to `Complex`, obtaining a symmetric operator with a single implementation.

Comment: What is your opinion on D's Uniform Function Call Syntax? So instead of Extensions Methods which IIUC provide free function syntax to member functions, D goes the other way around and provides member function syntax for free functions. So during name lookup, if `obj.fun()` does not find a member `Obj::fun()`, it continues to look for a free function `fun(Obj const&)`. This enables natural "infix" chaining of function calls. See e.g. http://www.drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/component-programming-in-d/240008321?pgno=4 Would this also suffer from the conversion issues you mention?

Comment: @rhalbersma: I don't know D, I know *some* of the features in the language and that they do look good on paper, but I have never *used* or *learnt* it in depth. To answer your question I would have to be much more familiar with the conversion rules in the language and how different features interact. My first impression is that if overload resolution works in the same way than in C++ it would solve the conversion problem. *But* depending on how lookup is performed (is it really *after*, maybe at the same time?) it might have other issues.

Comment: Everything is not an object.

I see some kind of faulty thinking here.

class is possibly some data with a number of functions.
object is some memory marked with class.
actually in c++ you can mark any memory as of any class (reinterpret_cast).
so everything can be an object.

Comment: @yatagarasu: Doing a `reinterpret_cast` does not make a random piece of memory an object of the destination type. The language has a set of rules as of when an *object* lifetime starts and ends, and the specification of the language uses the term *object* to refer both to instances of user defined types and instances of fundamental types, although in OO parlance those are not objects. Now back to the *everything is an object mindset* (note the italics), I am quite familiar that in none of the languages discussed here that is the case, which is one of the big flaws in Java, for example.

Comment: ... and I am talking in particular about the *need* to enclose everything in a class (instantiable or not, another imprecision in the answer, again *italics*) trying to force a design in which *everything* is designed as O[bject] (i.e. Object *Imposed* rather than Object Oriented). The flaw is that not everything can be mapped as such, which leads to Booch's *utility classes*, for example, which are **not** classes [\*], but an artificial grouping of functions that don't apply to an object of a particular type. [\* Utility classes fall outside of any taxonomy of the domain]

Comment: **There are no extension methods in C++, nor are they needed.**.
That is your opinion. I think every language should offer that syntactic sugar.

Comment: @Alexis: Maybe a slightly pedantic point, but the statement is not really an opinion.  Extension methods are not needed.  They are, as you put it, syntactic sugar.  An extension method really is just a free function in disguise.  That being said, I also think they would be a nice addition.  Whether they are "needed" or not is kind of beside the point.

Comment: @AlexisPautrot It can be more than just syntactic sugar - there can be side-effects.  One of my biggest fears of extension methods is implementation.  Suppose you extend another library's class with `foo()` which writes to a log on failure.  In the future, you upgrade the library that now provides its own implementation of `foo()`.  It's likely this will now be the preferred call over your extension method.  But the library has no knowledge of your logging system and so log omissions silently occur.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas missed the entire point of extensions methods in C#. They're not to enable free-floating methods, but to implicitly pass `this` pointer to them. Consider LINQ's `iter.Where(x -> x.IsSomething).Select(x -> x.Value).Sum()`. It's perfectly doable this whithout ExtM, but then you get reverse order.

Comment: @Agent_L: I think you misunderstood my answer. I know that extension methods create new *methods*, not free functions. The point I was trying to raise is that in C++ there are free functions, and those can be used to extend the functionality of a type *without* having to add new member functions (*methods*). On the order of code (with the LINQ example), there are currently two proposals to allow calling free functions with member function syntax. Currently you can already build the same type of operations without reversing the order in existing libraries without reordering the query.

Comment: ... the question is whether a *where* and *select* are part of the *iter* interface or a different thing. I personally don't think it is, what you want (opinion) is a range library with composable algorithms, and for that Eric Niebler's library seems to be taking the right approach (again, opinion :))

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Yeah, entire LINQ (`Where`, `Select`, `Sum` and more) are generic extensions for generic iterator, often returning the very type they take as extension-`this`. My point is that in C# even those extension methods are not free floating (but members of a `static` class). ExtM's serve merely as syntactic sugar (adding no "real" functionality) so your "There are no extension methods in C++, nor are they needed" seems not fitting.  N4165 and N4174 are exactly what OP meant and what you deemed "not needed".

Comment: @Agent_L: I still don't think they are needed :) For the LINQ particular problem, I believe in Stepanov's STL approach, where iterator is a concept and algorithms apply to iterators *externally*. This can be achieves without reversing the order of operations by using operator overloading, for example, which is shown in Eric's library with code like: `vector<int> ints = read_ints() | sort | unique;` which uses a source `read_ints`, operates on it by sorting it, and then filters reducing duplicates. Should it read: `read_ints().sort().unique()`? I guess that is a matter of taste.

Comment: @Agent_L: A different example from the documentation reads: `auto rng = vi | filter([](int i){ return i%1 == 0; }) | transform([](int i) { return to_string(i); });` to produce a range of `std::string` objects with the even values out of the range (or container) `vi`.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Well, I guess such operator overloading is equally controversial to N4174 :)

Comment: @TemplateRex What you are describing is essentially the same as the C# extension methods that OP was referring to, except that in C# you have to explicitly "mark" those methods as such for the compiler to consider them, which is done by prefixing the first argument with the `this` keyword (they can still be used as normal functions of course). (I'm ignoring the fact that they have to reside in a `static class` since this is little more than a fancy OO-ish way of making free functions.)

Comment: This seems more like a critical weakness in C++. It wants to be object oriented, but at the same time doesn't want to be object oriented; the language is schizophrenic due to poor design choices.

Comment: @Krythic: What would be a *true* object oriented language? I cannot but smile when I see comments claiming that certain, quite successful, language or product if full of *poor design choices*.  There are two types of programing languages, those that people complain about and those that people don't use.

Comment: http://mariusbancila.ro/blog/2014/10/15/extension-methods-in-cpp/ Trying to justify C++ doesn't need extension method is like trying to justify a person don't need money to live a happy life. Can't say it's wrong. It's just not a heathy attitude.

Comment: @XiaoguoGe: you are missing my point. ADL makes free functions in the same namespace as the type part of the interface of the class. The language already supports extension of classes externally. The post you link refers a paper from Bjarne among a few papers (Herb Sutter wrote another, they coauthored a third) discussing compile time transformations of calls facilitate generic code by removing the need to know whether something is a member or free function. But this is not an enabling feature, while in Java you cannot extend a class at all, in C++ this is supported since C++98.

Comment: Extension method is actually very handy. The free function thing require the programmer to already know the existence of the functions. If extension method is present, I only need to 'dot' the object and will see it on suggestions. Sometime patching a 3rd party lib with shortcut ext methods would really help make things smooth. Of course you can also enclose the free functions in a namespace to enjoy the 'dot' suggestion but that would just make the code line longer.

Comment: There are cases where Extensions Methods (in general possibility of augmenting class with methods and attributes) will be quite handy. One good example is data classes generated by some tools such as [Microsoft Bond](https://github.com/Microsoft/bond) or [Google Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/). Having extensions allows augmenting those classes with necessary processing and action methods, and perhaps additional properties which will not be persisted but serve computational and presentation purposes.

Comment: @Nick That speaks to the tooling disparity between C# and C++, not to language design.

Comment: There are no extension methods in C++, nor are they needed... That is your opinion. In a complex system, extension methods could improve readability and this always a value.

Comment: I like the thorough answer, but the part about `sum` was very subjective. as a young developer I've grown used to using intellisense, and a `a.sum(b)` gives better intellisense support than `sum(a,b)`

Comment: [Pipeline-rewrite operator](https://github.com/brevzin/cpp_proposals/issues/82), which is basically a syntax to introduce extension methods,  may be voted for C++26, so this is another answer that falls short saying that C++ doesn't need that feature, and after few years that feature actually risks to be introduced into the standard.

Comment: @ceztko "risks to be introduced into the standard"? Are you against it? Pipeline-rewrite is a different feature to extension methods. It's an opt-in for the call site, rather than the definition, which means that it's applicable to existing code.

Comment: @Coolguy what about `a + b`?

Comment: @Caleth no, mine was irony. I am mostly favorable to that syntax

Comment: @Caleth yes I like that more than `a.sum(b)`. but 'sum' is a special example that happens to have a special character we can use as operator. other methods dont have this fancy. imagine `dotProduct` or `crossProduct`, using `.` and `x` would just create more confusion than it resolves

Answer (score 37):

Boost Range Library's approach use operator|().

```
r | filtered(p);
```

I can write trim for string as follows in the same way, too.

```
#include <string>

namespace string_extension {

struct trim_t {
    std::string operator()(const std::string& s) const
    {
        ...
        return s;
    }
};

const trim_t trim = {};

std::string operator|(const std::string& s, trim_t f)
{
    return f(s);
}

} // namespace string_extension

int main()
{
    const std::string s = "  abc  ";

    const std::string result = s | string_extension::trim;
}
```

Comment: Very cool technique, I think it's the best we can achieve with c++. Also it can be made work with functions with parameters.

Answer (score 13):

This is the closest thing that I have ever seen to extension methods in C++. Personally i like the way it can be used, and possibly this it the closest we can get to extension methods in this language. But there are some disadvantages:

- It may be complicated to implement
- Operator precedence may be not that nice some times, this may cause surprises

A solution:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class regular_class {

    public:

        void simple_method(void) const {
            cout << "simple_method called." << endl;
        }

};


class ext_method {

    private:

        // arguments of the extension method
        int x_;

    public:

        // arguments get initialized here
        ext_method(int x) : x_(x) {

        }


        // just a dummy overload to return a reference to itself
        ext_method& operator-(void) {
            return *this;
        }


        // extension method body is implemented here. The return type of this op. overload
        //    should be the return type of the extension method
        friend const regular_class& operator<(const regular_class& obj, const ext_method& mthd) {

            cout << "Extension method called with: " << mthd.x_ << " on " << &obj << endl;
            return obj;
        }
};


int main()
{ 
    regular_class obj;
    cout << "regular_class object at: " << &obj << endl;
    obj.simple_method();
    obj<-ext_method(3)<-ext_method(8);
    return 0;
}
```

This is not my personal invention, recently a friend of mine mailed it to me, he said he got it from a university mailing list.

Comment: That looks suspiciously like a (light-hearted) lightning talk I did last year: http://www.slideshare.net/phil_nash/c-extension-methods-18678294
I don't mind if that's where it came from - just curious if it is or if this was independently discovered - any idea?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot look up the source from where this might came. I only know that the guy who mailed it to that university mailing list is a leader of a webkit developer group here in Szeged, Hungary. He is a very experienced programmer but I do not know where did he collect this gem from. It is very well possible that it was your presentation. :) Anyway, congratulations for this discovery!

Answer (score 9):

The short answer is that you cannot do that. The long answer is that you can simulate it, but be aware that you'll have to create a lot of code as workaround (actually, I don't think there is an elegant solution).

In the discussion, a very complex workaround is provided using operator- (which is a bad idea, in my opinion). I guess that the solution provided in the dead link was more o less similar (since it was based on operator|).

This is based in the capability of being able to do more or less the same thing as an extension method with operators. For example, if you want to overload the ostream's operator<< for your new class Foo, you could do:

```
class Foo {
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &o, const Foo &foo);
    // more things...
};

ostream &operator<<(ostream &o, const Foo &foo)
{
  // write foo's info to o
}
```

As I said, this is the only similar mechanism availabe in C++ for extension methods. If you can naturally translate your function to an overloaded operator, then it is fine. The only other possibility is to artificially overload an operator that has nothing to do with your objective, but this is going to make you write very confusing code.

The most similar approach I can think of would mean to create an extension class and create your new methods there. Unfortunately, this means that you'll need to "adapt" your objects:

```
class stringext {
public:
    stringext(std::string &s) : str( &s )
        {}
    string trim()
        {  ...; return *str; }
private:
    string * str;
};
```

And then, when you want to do that things:

```
void fie(string &str)
{
    // ...
    cout << stringext( str ).trim() << endl;
}
```

As said, this is not perfect, and I don't think that kind of perfect solution exists.
Sorry.

Comment: An elegant solution would be to create function adaptor like what is done in PStade's [pipable adaptor](http://p-stade.sourceforge.net/boost/libs/egg/doc/html/boost_egg/function_adaptors.html#boost_egg.function_adaptors.pipable) or in [Linq's](http://pfultz2.github.com/Linq/) `range_extension`. They make it very simple to write a pipable(or extension-like) function.

Comment: I think your are basically suggesting the approach taken by the BOOST C++ library, explained by @Akira Takahashi in this very same page. Please note that the operator | is used for bitwise OR operator, and you are changing the natural meaning of the operator, potentially introducing confusion to future readers of the code.
That's why I don't think it is an elegant solution. A true elegant solution would be to introduce extension methods, in a similar way that C# does: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx

Comment: I was responding to the "you'll have to create a lot of code as workaround (actually, I don't think there is an elegant solution)" part. Using a function adaptor does not require writing a lot of code. Unfortunately, boost does not have a function adaptor. As far as using bitwise OR operator to mean piping, is the same as using the bitshift operators as stream operators. It seems like the pipe operator is becoming establish in the C++ community with several libraries using it, including boost.

Answer (score 4):

To elaborate more on @Akira answer, `operator|` can be used to extend existing classes with functions that take parameters too. Here an example that I'm using to extend Xerces XML library with find functionalities that can be easily concatenated:

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>

#include <xercesc/dom/DOMElement.hpp>

#define _U16C // macro that converts string to char16_t array

XERCES_CPP_NAMESPACE_BEGIN
    struct FindFirst
    {
        FindFirst(const std::string& name);
        DOMElement * operator()(const DOMElement &el) const;
        DOMElement * operator()(const DOMElement *el) const;
    private:
        std::string m_name;
    };

    struct FindFirstExisting
    {
        FindFirstExisting(const std::string& name);
        DOMElement & operator()(const DOMElement &el) const;
    private:
        std::string m_name;
    };

    inline DOMElement & operator|(const DOMElement &el, const FindFirstExisting &f)
    {
        return f(el);
    }

    inline DOMElement * operator|(const DOMElement &el, const FindFirst &f)
    {
        return f(el);
    }

    inline DOMElement * operator|(const DOMElement *el, const FindFirst &f)
    {
        return f(el);
    }

    inline FindFirst::FindFirst(const std::string & name)
        : m_name(name)
    {
    }

    inline DOMElement * FindFirst::operator()(const DOMElement &el) const
    {
        auto list = el.getElementsByTagName(_U16C(m_name));
        if (list->getLength() == 0)
            return nullptr;

        return static_cast<DOMElement *>(list->item(0));
    }

    inline DOMElement * FindFirst::operator()(const DOMElement *el) const
    {
        if (el == nullptr)
            return nullptr;

        auto list = el->getElementsByTagName(_U16C(m_name));
        if (list->getLength() == 0)
            return nullptr;

        return static_cast<DOMElement *>(list->item(0));
    }

    inline FindFirstExisting::FindFirstExisting(const std::string & name)
        : m_name(name)
    {
    }

    inline DOMElement & FindFirstExisting::operator()(const DOMElement & el) const
    {
        auto list = el.getElementsByTagName(_U16C(m_name));
        if (list->getLength() == 0)
            throw runtime_error(string("Missing element with name ") + m_name);

        return static_cast<DOMElement &>(*list->item(0));
    }

XERCES_CPP_NAMESPACE_END
```

It can be used this way:

```
auto packetRate = *elementRoot | FindFirst("Header") | FindFirst("PacketRate");
auto &decrypted = *elementRoot | FindFirstExisting("Header") | FindFirstExisting("Decrypted");
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of complex (and reasonable) answers, just for completeness, a simple solution if you want your operations on the right is to write a wrapper with an implicit constructor and/or conversion operator, which is essentially how `std::reference_wrapper` behaves.

```
struct Ext
{
    const int& Value;
    Ext(const int& v) : Value(v) {}
    int Double() { return Value * 2; }
};

int main()
{
    int someInt = 9;
    Ext moreInt = someInt;
    return moreInt.Double() + Ext().Double(12);
}
```

Obviously this makes more sense with more methods and with something that isn't `int`.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable *kinda* extension methods for your own class/struct or for some specific type in some scope. See rough solution below.

```
class Extensible
{
public:
    template<class TRes, class T, class... Args>
    std::function<TRes(Args...)> operator|
        (std::function<TRes(T&, Args...)>& extension)
    {
        return [this, &extension](Args... args) -> TRes
        {
            return extension(*static_cast<T*>(this), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        };
    }
};
```

Then inherit your class from this and use like

```
class SomeExtensible : public Extensible { /*...*/ };
std::function<int(SomeExtensible&, int)> fn;
SomeExtensible se;
int i = (se | fn)(4);
```

Or you can declare this operator in cpp file or namespace.

```
//for std::string, for example
template<class TRes, class... Args>
std::function<TRes(Args...)> operator|
    (std::string& s, std::function<TRes(std::string&, Args...)>& extension)
{
    return [&s, &extension](Args... args) -> TRes
    {
        return extension(s, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    };
}

std::string s = "newStr";
std::function<std::string(std::string&)> init = [](std::string& s) {
    return s = "initialized";
};
(s | init)();
```

Or even wrap it in macro (I know, it's generally bad idea, nevertheless you can):

```
#define ENABLE_EXTENSIONS_FOR(x) \
template<class TRes, class... Args> \
std::function<TRes(Args...)> operator| (x s, std::function<TRes(x, Args...)>& extension) \
{ \
    return [&s, &extension](Args... args) -> TRes \
    { \
        return extension(s, std::forward<Args>(args)...); \
    }; \
}

ENABLE_EXTENSIONS_FOR(std::vector<int>&);
```

Answer (score -1):

This syntactic sugar isn't available in C++, but you can define your own namespace and write pure static classes, using `const` references as the first parameter.

For example, I was struggling using the STL implementation for some array operations, and I didn't like the syntaxis, I was used to JavaScript's functional way of how array methods worked.

So, I made my own namespace `wh` with the class `vector` in it, since that's the class I was expecting to use these methods, and this is the result:

```
//#ifndef __WH_HPP
//#define __WH_HPP

#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>

namespace wh{
    template<typename T>
    class vector{
        public:
        static T reduce(const std::vector<T> &array, const T &accumulatorInitiator, const std::function<T(T,T)> &functor){
            T accumulator = accumulatorInitiator;

            for(auto &element: array)   accumulator = functor(element, accumulator);

            return accumulator;
        }

        static T reduce(const std::vector<T> &array, const T &accumulatorInitiator){
            return wh::vector<T>::reduce(array, accumulatorInitiator, [](T element, T acc){return element + acc;});
        }

        static std::vector<T> map(const std::vector<T> &array, const std::function<T(T)> &functor){
            std::vector<T> ret;

            transform(array.begin(), array.end(), std::back_inserter(ret), functor);

            return ret;
        }

        static std::vector<T> filter(const std::vector<T> &array, const std::function<bool(T)> &functor){
            std::vector<T> ret;

            copy_if(array.begin(), array.end(), std::back_inserter(ret), functor);

            return ret;
        }

        static bool all(const std::vector<T> &array,  const std::function<bool(T)> &functor){
            return all_of(array.begin(), array.end(), functor);
        }

        static bool any(const std::vector<T> &array, const std::function<bool(T)> &functor){
            return any_of(array.begin(), array.end(), functor);
        }
    };
}

//#undef __WH_HPP
```

I wouldn't inherit nor compose a class with it, since I've never been able to do it peacefully without any side-effects, but I came up with this, just `const` references.

The problem of course, is the extremely verbose code you have to make in order to use these static methods:

```cpp
int main()
{
    vector<int> numbers = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    numbers = wh::vector<int>::filter(numbers, [](int number){return number < 3;});
    numbers = wh::vector<int>::map(numbers,[](int number){return number + 3;});
    for(const auto& number: numbers)    cout << number << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

If only there was syntactic sugar that could make my static methods have some kind of more common syntax like:

```
myvector.map([](int number){return number+2;}); //...
```