# C++ add indexer operator to existing class without its modification

Tags: c++

I have a thirdparty C++ class I don't want to change.

I would like to write a wrapper which would behave like indexer operator without modification of the original class. I can do it using a helper class and proxy pattern, but is there something like [extensions in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx). Something like friend indexer operator?

Comment: You mean `operator []`?  Can you subclass the existing class?

Comment: I know C++, but I (and possibly others reading this) don't know what a C# extension is. Care to elaborate?

Comment: Subclass it if you need access to protected methods/variables. Aggregate it if you don't: [prefer composition over inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance)

Comment: C# extensions - I have put link into question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use public inheritance to overload `operator[]` then it is the easiest way to go.

Unfortunately `operator[]` cannot be non-member, so defining it as non-member function is not possible.

Comment: Public inheritance is not necessary at all. You can also inherit privately or use aggregation. Or, you could use a reference/pointer to the original object withou any ownership implications.

Comment: True - I've just written that it is probably the easiest way.

Comment: @qub1n also have in mind that unlike C# "indexer" operator in C++ can accept only one parameter to be properly invoked

Comment: As for extension methods see the post of dennis from the thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463009/extension-methods-in-c it is for my knowledge the best way of imitating extension methods in c++

Comment: OK, "operator[] cannot be non-member" is fine answer to me.