# C++ call method on object with the object itself as parameter

Tags: c++, oop, methods, openframeworks

In python you can, for example, call array.sort() and it will sort the array it is called on. However, I now have the following code snippet

```
void drawClickableRectangle(ClickableRectangle recto){
        ofSetHexColor(0xffffff);             // just some syntax from the library I'm using
        ofFill();
        ofDrawRectangle(recto.xpos, recto.ypos, recto.width, recto.height);
    }
```

and then call this method here:

```
ClickableRectangle recto(1,1,100,100);
recto.drawClickableRectangle(recto);
```

This is the full class:

```
class ClickableRectangle
{
    // Access specifier
public:


    // Data Members
    int xpos, ypos, width, height;
    ClickableRectangle(int x1, int y1, int width1, int height1){
        xpos = x1;
        ypos = y1;
        width = width1;
        height = height1;
    };
    // Member Functions()
    int getxpos()
    {
        return xpos;
    }
    int getypos(){
        return ypos;
    }
    int getwidth(){
        return width;
    }
    void drawClickableRectangle(ClickableRectangle recto){
        ofSetHexColor(0xffffff);
        ofFill();
        ofRect(recto.xpos,recto.ypos, recto.width, recto.height);
        //ofDrawRectangle(recto.xpos, recto.ypos, recto.width, recto.height);
    }
```

Is there a way to make the function call "reflexive"? So I can just call it like:

```
recto.drawClickableRectange();
```

I'm relatively new to C++, but not to programming in general. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extension methods in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463009/extension-methods-in-c)

Comment: Is `ClickableRectangle` your own class or is it part of library?

Comment: `drawClickableRectangle(){ drawClickableRectangle(*this); }` ?

Comment: There's something you're not telling us. As written, `drawClickableRectangle` can only be called as `drawClickableRectangle(recto)`. In order to call it as `recto.drawClickableRectangle(recto)` it would have to be a member function of `ClicakbleRectangle`. And if it's a member function, it doesn't need an argument. If you remove the argument from the function's declaration and definition it can simply be applied to the object that it's called on: `recto.drawClickableRectangle()`.

Comment: Are you asking if you can use dot `.` operator to call method on the object? Yes you can, just add the method to your object class and use `this` (or `*this`) to reference the object

Comment: It also needs to be `drawClickableRectangle(ClickableRectangle& recto)` if you want to change the `ClickableRectangle` from the call site

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Yeah the ClickableRectangle is my own, but ofDrawRectangle is a library class.

Comment: @PeteBecker Updated with the full class. Oh okay! That's exactly what I wanted to know.

Comment: @KillzoneKid Oh so like Chris Drew did? That actually makes a lot of sense, thanks!

Comment: @NathanOliver Does the way I currently do it make a new object in memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in the same way as python, no.

In python, you can

```
def unattached(fake_self):
    return fake_self.x

class Thing:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 42

Thing.method = unattached

thing = Thing()
print (thing.method())
print (unattached(thing))
```

Because there's no difference between a free function with an explicit first paramter and a instance method with an implicit first parameter.

In C++, you can't change a `class` at runtime, and a member function has a different type to a free function.

```
struct Thing {
    int x = 42;
    int method() const { return this->x; }
}

int unattached(const Thing * thing) { return thing->x; }
```

The type of `unattached` is `int (*)(const Thing *)`, whereas `method` is a `int (const Thing::*)()`. These are different types, you can't switch one for the other. You *can* however construct a `std::function<int(const Thing *)>` from *either* of them, but you can only use that with the free function syntax `func(thing)`, as it isn't a member of `Thing`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is there any problem in doing it like recto.draw(recto)? Because I can imagine it changes the instance of recto through shallow copying?

Comment: If you can add a `draw` method to `ClickableRectangle`, it doesn't need a second `ClickableRectangle` as an explicit parameter, it already has `this`. Separately, `void drawClickableRectangle(ClickableRectangle recto)` *copies* it's argument, anything that happens to `recto` inside it does not affect the object you call it with.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this in C++:

```
class ClickableRectangle {

    public int xpos;
    public int ypos;
    public int width;
    public int height;

    void drawClickableRectangle(){
        ofSetHexColor(0xffffff);             // just some syntax from the library I'm using
        ofFill();
        ofDrawRectangle(xpos, ypos, width, height);
    }
}
```

Then in your main function, call it like this:

```
int main(){

    ClickableRectangle recto;
    recto.xpos = 1;
    recto.ypos = 1;
    recto.width = 100;
    recto.height = 100;
    recto.drawClickableRectange();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense, I'll try that!