# Is it possible to define a extension method on a specific typed tuple?

Tags: c++

I have a tuple which represents a 3d point coordinate.

Is it possible to define a "extension" method on this tuple with specific type arguments. The extension method (named `move`) would mutate the tuple and have a param of a value of enum

```cpp
std::tuple<int, int, int> myPosition;
// what I want to do is:
myPosition.move(Directions::UP);
```

Is this possible? Or should I define a wrapper struct for position?

Comment: No, it's not possible. What's wrong with just using a function? (C++ is not object-obsessed.)

Comment: Don’t use tuples for custom types, that isn’t their purpose and is generally a bad idea. Define a custom type.

Comment: @molbdnilo Yes that makes sense, I think it's possible in C# and I prefer the readability of it being a `myPosition.move(Directions::UP)` rather than `move(myPosition, Directions::UP)`. Post that as answer and I will accept

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extension methods in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463009/extension-methods-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5466499/10732434) I edited a very cool technique to fit your requirements:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

typedef std::tuple<int, int, int> Position;

enum Direction
{
    UP = 1,
    DOWN = 2,
    LEFT = 3,
    RIGHT = 4
};

// select any operator that accepts two arguments
void operator>(Position pos, std::function<void(Position)> binded_extension)
{
    binded_extension(pos);
}

// the usual method for such task, we will reference to it
void hidden_move(Position pos, Direction dir)
{
    std::cout << "Position "
    << std::get<0>(pos) << ' '
    << std::get<1>(pos) << ' '
    << std::get<2>(pos) << ' '
    << "has been moved in direction " << dir << '\n';
}

struct extension_move
{
    std::function<void(Position)> operator()(Direction dir)
    {
        return std::bind(hidden_move, std::placeholders::_1, dir);
    }
};

// choose calling name for extension method here
extension_move move = {};

int main()
{
    Position myPosition = {1, 2, 3};

    /* overloading the dot operator is not that easy...
       but we still get pretty similar syntax
    myPosition.move(Direction::UP); */
    myPosition>move(Direction::UP);

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see instead of `myPosition.move(UP)` you have to call `myPosition>move(UP)`. You can even select other operator like `|` or `^`.