# std::function with unordered_map<K, V>::value_type as a parameter type is not accepted

Tags: c++, std-function

I'm practicing my C++ skills and while trying to mimic C# `IEnumerable.Where` extension for C++ unordered_map I encountered an error which I can't understand.

I am using an example I took from another StackOverflow post for implementing an extension method as elegant as it gets. Instead of calling the function with `->`, it uses `<-` which may be confusing but I liked it better than a static method which gets two parameters.
The link is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21222723).

So my implementation is this:

```
template<class K, class V>
class Where2 {
    std::function<bool(std::unordered_map<K, V>::value_type)> m_Predicate;
public:

    Where2(std::function<bool(std::unordered_map<K, V>::value_type)> i_Predicate) : m_Predicate(i_Predicate) {}

    Where2<K, V>& operator-(void) {
        return *this;
    }

    friend std::unordered_map<K, V> operator< (const std::unordered_map<K, V>& i_Obj, const Where2<K, V>& i_Ext) {
        std::unordered_map<K, V> result;
        std::copy_if(i_Obj.begin(), i_Obj.end(), std::inserter(result, result.end()), i_Ext.m_Predicate);
        return result;
    }
};
```

The error I get is:
error C2974: 'std::function': invalid template argument for '_Fty', type expected

Any advice?

Comment: Probably missing `typename` right before `std::unordered_map`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, Thanks, adding `typename` as suggested did solved my problem.