# Edge cases when replacing a type alias with inheritance

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a type `Point` that's simply an alias for `Vector3`: `using Point = Vector3;`

I'd like to be able to add functionality to `Point`, but no additional state.  So I'd like to replace it with a class inheriting from `Vector3`:

```
class Point : public Vector3 {
  using Base = Vector3;
  using Base::Base;

  Point(const Base& base) : Base(base) {}
  Point(Base&&) : Base(std::move(base)) {}

  Point& operator=(const Base& base) { 
    Base::operator=(base); 
    return *this; 
  }

  Point& operator=(Base&& base) {
    Base::operator(std::move(base));
    return *this;
  }
};
```

This inherits the base class constructors and allows converting/moving values of `Vector3` to `Point` since we could do that freely before.

The only thing that you could do before that you can't do with this method is freely casting pointers.  `Point*` -> `Vector3*` still works, but `Vector3*` -> `Point*` won't work implicitly anymore.

Are there any other corner cases when replacing a typedef in this fashion?

Edit: I've found one gotcha so far, you can't forward declare a type alias, so you might have had users work around that by re-typedefing in their headers: `typedef Vector3 Point`, which will break with the refactor.

Comment: Add functionality through free standing functions.

Comment: Another option is mimicking *extension methods* in C++, q.v. https://stackoverflow.com/q/5463009/4641116

Comment: Not an option if you want to add a nested class.

Comment: Adding a nested class is contrary to *...but no additional state*.

Comment: A nested class doesn't add any state to the class, it just namespaces it and makes it `friend` effectively.  I'm doing this so that I can modify my Point type consistently with how we're modifying some other things (that are already classes).

Comment: My misunderstanding, I presumed the nested class would be an instance member variable.

Comment: For the gotchas list: if templates are involved (which they aren't in the example), it can be difficult to forward declare a template.  (I'm not sure how `<iosfwd>` does its magic for `<iostream>`.)

Comment: Fortunately no templates at this level at least, the Vector3 class inherits from a templated base but it's not visible.

Comment: Template metaprogramming would be able to tell the difference; e.g. something like `template <typename T> std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, Vector3>> DoSomething();`

Comment: While `Point` and `Vector3` are convertible both ways, you would now be making copies where none were made before. This may affect code that relies on the identify of an object (that is, where the address matters), not just the value.

Comment: If `Vector3` was an aggregate, certain initialization patterns that worked with `Vector3` may not work with `Point`, which is not an aggregate anymore.

Comment: That's a good catch, Vector3's not an aggregate fortunately though